# streaming charts with raphaelJS

Tags: graph, charts, streaming, raphael

Has anyone ever tried to create something like [this](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/4747/streamingchart.png) using raphaelJS?

I need to create timeline charts and fill the space between with a particular color and opacity.

Is raphaelJS a good thing to start with? 
I also checked gRaphaelJS, but it lacks customizable filling (it's always the same color as the graph and it's always a fixed opacity).